# Having problems with simple jQuery snippet

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having problems with simple jQuery snippet. Here is the markup:

```
        <div class="banner">
            <div class="bannerInnerRight">
                <span class="box5"><h4>Reviews</h4></span>
                <span class="box6"><h4>Mission Statement</h4></span>
                <span class="box7"><h4>Serving Areas</h4></span>
                <span class="box8"></span>
            </div><!-- bannerInnerRight -->
        </div><!-- banner -->
```

The `h4`s are being hidden using css (`display:'none'`). When each span is hovered over I want its respective `h4` to show.

My attempt:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('div.banner > div > span').mouseover(function() {
        $(this > h4).show();
    });

});
```

I must be using the `this` keyword wrong, how do I get this to work?

Comment: What is CSS styling for span? If it is the default (inline), you have the problem: when h4 is hidden, there is nothing to hover over.

Comment: Minor structural comment - `h4`, being a block element, should not be placed within a `span`, which is an inline element.

Comment: @Ryan: My thought, too. Span could be styled to be block but would still be `invalid` to contain h4. Nevertheless, if it is inline than it collapses when empty (i.e. elements hidden) so there is nothing to hover, regardless of the methods presented below.

Comment: Also, $(this > h4).show(); is not syntactically correct. it first evaluates (this > h4) which is probably undefined or false and then passes it as an argument to $()... so this line would read like $(undefined).show() or $(false).show()

Comment: span is styled to display block and I don't care about validation as long as it works in all browsers ;)

Comment: @Joe: Deliberately ignoring standards is not as safe as you might think. Try to put "form" into "tbody" (e.g. you want a table of elements that could be edited, added, removed independantly) and see what happens. It is good practice to adjust your style to standards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$(this).find("h4").show();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$(this).find("h4").show();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("h4", $this).show();
```

The second parameter allows you to specify what you want to search in.

Comment: Context for the win. This method should be faster than using `.find()`, due to one less function call.

Comment: @Ryan: Context is slower. It gets flipped around into `$(this).find("h4").show()` then starts over. [source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.4.4/src/core.js#L171-175)

Comment: Well then. That's unfortunate. I rescind my previous comment.

Comment: If it gets changed into a find call, that wouldn't change the speed when compared to the accepted answer and I think this is more readable. Though I agree that is a bit unfortunate.

Answer (score 0):

How about the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.bannerInnerRight').find('span').mouseover(function() {
        $(this).find('h4').show();
    });

});
```